# Как на языке Python сделать Telegram бота, который будет рассылать сообщения другим пользователям Телеграма, зная TelegramID этого пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Python сделать Telegram бота, который будет рассылать сообщения другим пользователям Телеграма, зная  TelegramID этого пользователя?

Comment: Создать бота с которым эти люди начнут общение, ну либо же с помощью библиотеки `telethon`, но аккаунт, с которого будут рассылаться сообщения, быстро уйдет в бан.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Телеграм-бота, который первый отправляет сообщения, создать невозможно. К боту сначала должен обратиться пользователь. Это предусмотрено телеграмом для контроля спам рассылок. Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) для питона. (там есть некоторые примеры). Но это уже будет не бот, а аккаунт.